# Which is better to display extra info on web page? Pop up when you click or when you hover?

Tags: html, user-interface, usability

I like to display more info on certain keywords in a web page. I don't want to send the visitor to another page and I prefer to show the extra info on top of the current page.

The keywords are in an html list. It's basically a list of features and I want to offer more info about the features. So I have two ideas based on having 'More Info' or '?' hyperlinks.

1. The user hovers on the link and a popup window shows up with the info and goes away when they hover away.
2. They click on the link, a popup window with an 'X' shows up and they click on the X to close.

Which one offers a better friendlier user experience?

I like #1 because they don't have to click to open and click to close but the disadvantage is that windows might open inadvertently while they are mousing over the page.

Answer (score 4):

Both are pretty annoying, but if I had to pick the lesser of two evils, I'd go with properly done mouseovers.

You can setup Javascript on the page to handle the accidental mouse over, and instead wait for a few seconds before displaying the popup window.

Comment: Preventing accidental mouse overs is a great idea, I wish more websites implemented this!

Comment: Good idea but the timing needs to be just right. Too long and a user might think the functionality is broken.

Answer (score 3):

What would your users expect? Try not to break those expectations.

Maybe try a hallway usability study, grabbing a handful of users as they walk past the office, and just ask them to tell you what they would expect. :)

Asking Stack Overflow is a good idea too, but you won't get the advantage of context, which is very important with usability testing.

As a user myself, I find it annoying when I move a mouse and something pops up unexpectedly. Even with a javascript delay (which is better), I still think it's unexpected that something would pop up when I didn't explicitly click on it.

But, that might vary depending on the context of your application.

Comment: I am a user and I said what I prefer. You are a user. How would you like it to be if you were a visitor?

Comment: Say it's a list of web hosting features like email and you want to know what 'email forwarding' means. I don't have the luxury to ask anyone live!

Answer (score 1):

People don't expect a pop-up on hover - I'd definitely go with the click.

**Edit / addition:** think about the website you visit every day - text and pictures are (generally) static, and hovering, at most, changes the colour or add underline to a link, or displays a small menu of clickable links.

When clicking on a link, you expect something to happen - a redirect to another page, a pop-up box with information, a form being submitted, etc.

I'm not saying this is the best way to do things, but it **is** the way 99% of the web works, and asking users to deal with pop-up boxes on hovers or the like is a good way to turn them away. I know I personally don't read any pages with double-underlined links; it's a good indication that an accidental break in scrolling to read the content might end up with my mouse over a link with an advertisement tied to it.

Having a little graphic beside clickable text, or otherwise denoting that clicking will lead to more information is a great way of providing contextual information without frustrating people. For most of the world, pop-ups without clicking still == advertisements or spyware.

**Edit / clarification:** I don't mean a pop-up in the **new window** sense, just a lightbox-style javascript pop-up. Don't take the user away from the page, and give them a very visible button to click to close the pop-up. I guess what I'm saying is that people don't expect something to happen without clicking, especially not if it's going to take up more space on the screen.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the "More Info" or "?" links. You are deliberately clicking to get more information. I know those annoying double line links but that's not what I am doing. These links are on the side and not in the middle of the text. They are mainly out of your regular reading pattern.

Comment: My idea to stay away from opening whole new pages because the extra information is just a few lines and if there a lot quite a few features, it seems it's cumbersome to open a new web page, read it and go back to the current page and trace with your eyes where you left off which is distracting.

Comment: and providing the extra info right next when you're reading seems to be more in the flow instead of opening several new pages.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree - don't pop up a whole new window - I was talking about a lightbox-style javascript popup...don't take the user away from the page, just give them a bit more information, and a very easy to see 'X' to close the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with the click option. There's a standard Way Things Work on the web which says that hovers are for information about the link itself and what action clicking on it will do ("See more comments", "Click for help", etc.), whereas clicking is what actually performs the action.

If you do decide to go with the hover option, make sure that you code it such that users can select the text in the popup. It's really annoying when you just want to copy some useful information somewhere and the GUI hides it before you can reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what the others have said, I would also prefer the click option.

The problem I have with the hover option is that, and maybe this is just me, if the hoverable area is on the small side, I have a hard time keeping my mouse still enough to keep hovering. The cursor tends to move off the link in the middle of reading and my nice help text disappears.

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of additional precedents to consider, you might want to consider the functionality of the [acronym](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_acronym.asp) and [abbr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp) HTML tags.  Both allow you to provide extra information on a particular piece of text in the page, and both work on the "hover" principle.

Answer (score 0):

Points to ponder:

- If items are so dense that everywhere you move the mouse something pops up on hover then do NOT do hover!
- Can you make hover show very brief info, and have click show more detail? This may be the best of both worlds if it works for you.
- Can you have a dedicated box that displays info when you hover? This may be better than any pop-up. Opinions vary...

In the end it's what works for your app, from your users' point of view.

Comment: for #1 we mentioned a popup delay.

Comment: yes, but even with delay you still have to move the mouse out of the area or you end up with something popping up. it's a personal nitpick, but don't like it.